# Trying to transit to a new UIView once "Login" button is clicked in AlertView

Tags: ios, alertview

I have searched for methods that allows me to transit to a new page once a button on alert view is clicked. Do I have to use the prepareForSegue method? Or is there any simpler method?

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

    if(buttonIndex ==0){
        //code goes here
    }

    if(buttonIndex ==1){
        NSString *username = [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text];
        NSString *password = [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:1] text];
        NSLog(@"Username:%@",username);
        NSLog(@"Password:%@",password);

        //Check if username and password tally if tally move on to Menu page
        MainPageViewController *anotherController = [[MainPageViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AnotherView" bundle:nil];

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:anotherController animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use alertview delegate method – `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` to know which button was clicked and you can perform subsequent operation on the same.

Comment: Hi thanks so much. I have used alertview delegate method to see which button was clicked. I have problem moving on to the next UIView when a specific button was clicked. Yup. Thanks in advance..